# MySQL root pwd is no more visible in the API Console

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine

In **Google Api Console**

1. I have successfully created an instance using **'Click to Deploy' LAMP.**
2. After Creation, the mysql root pwd was displayed for some moment in the API console, which I forgot to note it down and it is no more available in the API console.

**Any idea on how to retrieve this mysql root pwd or to reset it again?**

Comment: You can only create a LAMP stack per project using Click to Deploy and if you try to create a new one you should see all the settings of your current LAMP stack, including the root password. Otherwise, could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: This link should bring you back to the deployment page so you can retrieve the autogenerated root password:  https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/mc/template/lamp

Comment: thanks. i can retrieve root pwd

Answer (score 0):

First log on to your system as the user that the mysqld server runs as. Locate the .pid file that contains the server's process ID. The exact location and name of this file depend on your distribution, host name, and configuration. Common locations are /var/lib/mysql/, /var/run/mysqld/, and /usr/local/mysql/data/.

Then send a kill command to the mysql process using the following command using the path name of your .pid file instead:

shell> kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`

Create a text file containing the following statements replacing the password with your new one:

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Write the UPDATE and FLUSH statements each on a single line.

Start the MySQL server with the special --init-file option:

shell> mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &

After the server has started successfully, delete /home/me/mysql-init.You should now be able to connect to the MySQL server as root using the new password. Stop the server and restart it normally.

For your reference the link to the  MySQL documentation on this topic  can be found here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Just added the source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: It looks like you've just copied the link verbatim. Instead try to summarise the link but still provide valuable working instructions on how to reset the root password without people having to follow the link.